# Django Queryset return None instead 0

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a queryset in Django:

```
puntos_jornalero1 = Equipo.objects.filter(
    jlg1__puntos__etapa=2
).annotate(
    puntos_jornalero1=Sum('jlg1__puntos__puntos', default=0)
)
```

If I make the queryset without the filter, I get 0 or the Sum correctly, but if I want to have the filter but in this case, when the result is 0, I get None. I need 0 because after that I need to Sum again the results.

My models, my query and my template are like these and everything works is I don`t use filter() in the subqueries, but when I use it I get None instead 0 if the lid1 or lid2 or jlg1 or..... has not puntos (points) in the Etapa (Stage) filtered.

`Models.py:`

```py
class Equipo(models.Model):
    alias=models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    lid1=models.ForeignKey(Corredor,limit_choices_to={'lid':True, 'giro':True, 'tipo': "Rider"}, related_name="lid1", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lid2=models.ForeignKey(Corredor,limit_choices_to={'lid':True, 'giro':True, 'tipo': "Rider"}, related_name="lid2", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lid3=models.ForeignKey(Corredor,limit_choices_to={'lid':True, 'giro':True, 'tipo': "Rider"}, related_name="lid3", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lid4=models.ForeignKey(Corredor,limit_choices_to={'lid':True, 'giro':True, 'tipo': "Rider"}, related_name="lid4", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gre1=models.ForeignKey(Corredor,limit_choices_to={'gre':True, 'giro':True, 'tipo': "Rider"}, related_name="gre1", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gre2=models.ForeignKey(Corredor,limit_choices_to={'gre':True, 'giro':True, 'tipo': "Rider"}, related_name="gre2", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gre3=models.ForeignKey(Corredor,limit_choices_to={'gre':True, 'giro':True, 'tipo': "Rider"}, related_name="gre3", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    jlg1=models.ForeignKey(Corredor,limit_choices_to={'jor':True, 'giro':True, 'tipo': "Rider"}, related_name="jlg1", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    jlg2=models.ForeignKey(Corredor,limit_choices_to={'jor':True, 'giro':True, 'tipo': "Rider"}, related_name="jlg2", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Puntuacion (models.Model):
    etapa=models.IntegerField()
    dorsal=models.ForeignKey(Corredor, blank=True, null=True, related_name="puntos", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categoria=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    descripcion=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    puntos=models.IntegerField()

class Corredor (models.Model):
    dorsal=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    tipo=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

`Views.py:`

````py
def clasificacion_etapa2(request):
         puntos_lider1=Equipo.objects.filter(lid1__puntos__etapa=2).annotate(puntos_lider1=Coalesce(Sum('lid1__puntos__puntos'), Value(0)))
    puntos_lider2=Equipo.objects.filter(lid2__puntos__etapa=2).annotate(puntos_lider2=Coalesce(Sum('lid2__puntos__puntos'), Value(0)))
    puntos_lider3=Equipo.objects.filter(lid3__puntos__etapa=2).annotate(puntos_lider3=Coalesce(Sum('lid3__puntos__puntos'), Value(0)))
    puntos_lider4=Equipo.objects.filter(lid4__puntos__etapa=2).annotate(puntos_lider4=Coalesce(Sum('lid4__puntos__puntos'), Value(0)))
    puntos_gregario1=Equipo.objects.filter(gre1__puntos__etapa=2).annotate(puntos_gregario1=Coalesce(Sum('gre1__puntos__puntos'), Value(0)))
    puntos_gregario2=Equipo.objects.filter(gre2__puntos__etapa=2).annotate(puntos_gregario2=Coalesce(Sum('gre2__puntos__puntos'), Value(0)))
    puntos_gregario3=Equipo.objects.filter(gre3__puntos__etapa=2).annotate(puntos_gregario3=Coalesce(Sum('gre3__puntos__puntos'), Value(0)))
    puntos_jornalero1=Equipo.objects.filter(jlg1__puntos__etapa=2).annotate(puntos_jornalero1=Coalesce(Sum('jlg1__puntos__puntos'), Value(0)))
    puntos_jornalero2=Equipo.objects.filter(jlg2__puntos__etapa=2).annotate(puntos_jornalero2=Coalesce(Sum('jlg2__puntos__puntos'), Value(0)))```
 equipos=Equipo.objects.annotate(puntos_lider1=Subquery(puntos_lider1.values('puntos_lider1'),output_field=IntegerField()),puntos_lider2=Subquery(puntos_lider2.values('puntos_lider2'),output_field=IntegerField()),puntos_lider3=Subquery(puntos_lider3.values('puntos_lider3'),output_field=IntegerField()),puntos_lider4=Subquery(puntos_lider4.values('puntos_lider4'),output_field=IntegerField()),puntos_gregario1=Subquery(puntos_gregario1.values('puntos_gregario1'),output_field=IntegerField()),puntos_gregario2=Subquery(puntos_gregario2.values('puntos_gregario2'),output_field=IntegerField()),puntos_gregario3=Subquery(puntos_gregario3.values('puntos_gregario3'),output_field=IntegerField()),puntos_jornalero1=Subquery(puntos_jornalero1.values('puntos_jornalero1'),output_field=IntegerField()),puntos_jornalero2=Subquery(puntos_jornalero2.values('puntos_jornalero2'),output_field=IntegerField())).annotate(puntos_equipo=F('puntos_lider1')+F('puntos_lider2')+F('puntos_lider3')+F('puntos_lider4')+F('puntos_gregario1')+F('puntos_gregario2')+F('puntos_gregario3')+F('puntos_jornalero1')+F('puntos_jornalero2')).order_by('-puntos_equipo')

return render(request,"PorraApp/clasificacion_etapa2.html",{"equipos":equipos})
````

`Template file:`

```html
{% extends "PorraApp/base.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<h1 class="bg-success font-weight-bold text-dark py-4 px-5">CLASIFICACIÓN ETAPA 2</h1>
  <section class="my-4">
    <div class="container">
      <ol class="bg-success font-weight-bold text-dark py-4 px-5">
      {% for equipo in equipos %}
        
          <li>
            <h5 class="font-weight-bold"> {{equipo.alias}}</h5>
            <p>{{equipo.puntos_equipo}} PUNTOS</p>
              
          </li>
           
       
      {% endfor %} 
      </ol>
    </div>
  </section>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the filter removes all related elements. You can work with [**`Coalesce`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) to use `0` when there are no items, so:

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

puntos_jornalero1 = Equipo.objects.filter(
    jlg1__puntos__etapa=2
).annotate(
    puntos_jornalero1=Coalesce(Sum('jlg1__puntos__puntos'), Value(0))
)
```

Comment: I use Coalesce to make the queryset without the filter and it works correctly, but when I try to use Coalesce with the filter and there are not any row selected after the filter because in some cases there is no rows for that jlg1 in etapa 2, I get None and no 0. I need your help. I am working in that question a lot of time and it’s imposible for me to resolve it.

Comment: I have read in Django version 4.0 has been created default and empty_set_result_value for these cases, but I don’t know how to use it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Antonio: in your question you say you sum up the `puntos_jornalero1` if I understand it correctly? Can you edit the question and show how you sum up these?

Comment: I edited the question to give you all the information about the query.

Comment: Any idea to solve my problem? Thanks in advance. Maybe you know someone who can help me? Can you ask him o her about my question?